# Listing files using wildcards with Laravel Storage and AWS S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5.3

I am converting a Laravel (5.3) app to use AWS S3 as image storage. I need to programmatically get list of images whose names comply with a specific mask (eg 'FS_1054_*.JPG') which when I used local storage I could do easily with the glob() function.

Any suggestions as to how I could do this with S3?

Comment: what does your bucket look like? are you storing images like `folder/folder/FS_1054_01.JPG` ? you can search by `prefix` but its a little more difficult if your images are nested in folders like my example

Comment: Yes they are nested in folders.

Answer (score 20):

Suppose If you want to get all files then you can use this

```
Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles('');
```

It will return All file that have in your bucket. but if you want to look particular then

```
Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles('FolderName');
```

or

```
Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles('FolderName/2FolderName');
```

have a look of this image. when you want to look all files.

[image]

Comment: This also appears to be available as a static method: `Storage::allFiles($directory)`

Answer (score 6):

```
$storage = Storage::disk('s3');
$client = $storage->getAdapter()->getClient();
$command = $client->getCommand('ListObjects');
$command['Bucket'] = $storage->getAdapter()->getBucket();
$command['Prefix'] = 'path/to/FS_1054_';
$result = $client->execute($command);
foreach ($result['Contents'] as $file) {
    //do something with $file['Key']
}
```

Comment: I get S3Client successfully by  ``` $storage->getClient(); ```

Answer (score 3):

I have found an answer, though am happy to know if there is a better one.

Use `Storage::files(folder_name)` to list all files in the folder, this returns an array. Then use `array_where` and `starts_with` to filter the list:

```
$files = Storage::files(folder_name);

$files = array_where($files, function ($value, $key) use ($mask) {
   return starts_with(basename($value), $mask);
});
```

Comment: better way will be to store the file name in the db.. think about it what happen when you have million of images?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating subfolders based on the filename as the "index" by which you need to search, so you have something like:

```
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FS_1054/FS_1054_123.jpg
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FS_1054/FS_1054_124.jpg
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FS_1055/FS_1055_123.jpg
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FS_1055/FS_1055_124.jpg
etc...
```

So you can get the list using

```
Storage::disk('s3')->files('foo/bar/FS_1054')
```

Depending on how fine-grained you want to be able to search, you might need more nested folders:

```
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FS/1054/FS_1054_123.jpg
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FS/1054/FS_1054_124.jpg
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FS/1055/FS_1055_123.jpg
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FS/1055/FS_1055_124.jpg
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FT/1054/FT_1054_123.jpg
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FT/1054/FT_1054_124.jpg
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FT/1055/FT_1055_123.jpg
s3://bucket/foo/bar/FT/1055/FT_1055_124.jpg
etc...
```

Though this would allow you to:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles('foo/bar/FS')
(note: allFiles() used for recursive listing)
```

and

```
Storage::disk('s3')->files('foo/bar/FS/1054')
```